# How to set the time zone in the showDatePickerDialog's DayPicker

Tags: flutter, datepicker, timezone

I'm in need of a DatePickerDialog that's completely handled in UTC (for aviation), ignoring the phone's current time zone. Is it possible to use showDatePickerDialog() and set its DayPicker to UTC, or more specifically: have the current day (which is depicted in the theme's accent color) shown in UTC?

Example:

My phone is set to CET and it's 07-APR-2020 00:30 CET, which without DST is 06-APR-2020 23:30 UTC. I've managed to show the currently selected date on the 6th by using the showDatePicker() function like this:

```
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now().toUtc().subtract(Duration(days: 365)),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(days: 90)),
);
```

but the "current date" in the DayPicker is still in CET, demonstrated in the picture below.

[image]

Is there any way to change that so it uses the UTC value for the current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that wasn't possible - with [PR #54978](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/54978) it is.

Example from OP:

```
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  currentDate: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
  initialDate: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now().toUtc().subtract(const Duration(days: 365)),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().toUtc().add(const Duration(days: 90)),
);
```

Comment: I don't get how to do this with `currentDate`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Added the example from the OP

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, that showDatePicker returns only date and set local time to 00:00. So the only option for you is that you take result and change the DateTime manually to what you want.

```dart
          onTap: () async {
            var date = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
              firstDate: DateTime.now().toUtc().subtract(Duration(days: 365)),
              lastDate: DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(days: 90)),
            );
            if (date != null) {
              // here you go
              date = DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day, 0, 0);
            }
          },
```